# Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS] adapter not working with ubuntu 18 desktop

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, network-manager, realtek

I have a wireless adapter EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS] plugged into my Ubuntu desktop 18. My network manager sees the wireless networks but is unable to connect to the WiFi. I did a

```
 sudo lshw -C network

*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:11
       logical name: wlx74da38f6c0ca
       serial: 4a:b4:7d:3b:63:18
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=**rtl8192cu** driverversion=4.15.0-47-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What `lsmod` and `iwconfig` say?

You move forward based on the answer.
I think your driver is loaded correctly; and you can make sure about this by `sudo lsmod`.. you should be able to see the rtl 8188 driver listed. You have no driver issue.
I think your issue is in the configuration. Check `/etc/interfaces` and you should see no existence for any wireless configuration. Add the right wireless configuration that is suitable for the connection manager you use.